# Ошибка Type 'Soccer' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing'?

Tags: swift, парсер, swift3, parse.com

Подскажите как решается ошибка? очень буду благодарен.Раньше ее на xcode 8 не было.После обновления стала вылазить ошибка .Убирал уже PFSubclassing, но у меня при загрузки приложения требует PFSubclassing.
Вот такие ошибки :
 Parse.PFObject:52:21: Unavailable class method 'object()' was used to satisfy a requirement of protocol 'PFSubclassing'
Type 'Soccer' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing'

вот мой код

```
import Foundation
import Parse


class Soccer : PFObject,PFSubclassing {



    @NSManaged var matchS: String
    @NSManaged var imagePrS: PFFile
    @NSManaged var detailImageS : PFFile
    @NSManaged var detailTextS : String
    @NSManaged var detailPrognozS: String
    @NSManaged var detailTitleS: String




   class func parseClassName() -> String {

        return "soccer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка Type 'Soccer' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing' говорит о том что ваш класс Soccer не реализовал обязательные методы PFSubclassing протокола, покажите протокол

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Type 'Soccer' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing', как избавиться появилась после обновления Xcode 9?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722978/type-soccer-does-not-conform-to-protocol-pfsubclassing-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8)