# Type 'Soccer' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing', как избавиться появилась после обновления Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse.com

Добрый день! очень нуждаюсь  в помощи и не могу понять в чем ошибка.В Xcode версии 8 не выдавало ошибку.Увидел только один пример на английской версии.Не понял как ее исправить.И вроде там ситуация немного другая.Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Вот мой код и полная ошибка:

```
Parse.PFObject:52:21: Unavailable class method 'object()' was used to satisfy a requirement of protocol 'PFSubclassing'
Parse.PFSubclassing:24:33: Requirement 'object()' declared here


import Foundation
import Parse


class Soccer : PFObject,PFSubclassing {



    @NSManaged var matchS: String
    @NSManaged var imagePrS: PFFile
    @NSManaged var detailImageS : PFFile
    @NSManaged var detailTextS : String
    @NSManaged var detailPrognozS: String
    @NSManaged var detailTitleS: String


    class func parseClassName() -> String {

        return "Soccer"
    }
}
```

Comment: как версия Parse SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените

```
 class func parseClassName() -> String {
```

на

```
 static func parseClassName() -> String {
```

почистите кеш Shift+Cmd+K ну можно еще Build Folder очистить (иногда помогает убрать ошибки) Option+Shift+Command+K , если не поможет обновите SDK, этот баг вроде как поправили в версии 1.15.2

---

еще можно попробовать добавить

```
 #import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

в бридж хедер

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66627/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey-iskamov-type-soccer-does-not-conform-to-protoco).

Answer (score 1):

Ребята если выскакивает такая ошибка.Заново удалите весь cocoapods и podfile , и установите заново и ошибка исчезает.Должна быть Версия Parse 1.15.3.